# Need help modifying a SQL View

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL view created already & that view gives certain columns from a database table `Data`. Now, I want to modify that view in such a manner that it does not need to add any additional columns to the result & should match exactly with the same result as this view generated before. The only modification I want here is: There is a column called `PayDate` that the view takes from `Data` table. I need that column to have value depending on other column called `OrderType`. The `Data` table looks like :

```
Book    OrderType   PayDate      ValuDate
-------------------------------------------
FFF     CA          21/05/2015   NULL
BBB     CO          NULL         2/02/2014
EEE     IO          NULL         3/2/2014
QQQ     Dividend    02/02/2014   NULL
```

Currently, the view gives `OrderType` & `Paydate` as a result. Twist here is, for `OrderType = 'CA' OR 'Dvidend'` we have `PayDate` . For `OrderType = 'CO' OR 'IO'` we have `ValuDate`. Each time for 'CO' or 'IO' the value got is NULL. So here I want a CASE that will check if `OrderType` is 'CO' OR 'IO' it'll return `ValuDate` in PayDate column. And at places where `OrderType` is 'CA' or 'Dividend' give value of `PayDate` from `Data` table in `PayDate` column of the view.

PS : Do not want to add a `ValuDate` column here. All we need is just put the value of `ValueDate` in `PayDate` column of view if `OrderType` is 'CO' or 'IO'`

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[ABC]'))
BEGIN
    DROP VIEW [dbo].[ABC]
    PRINT '<<< DROPPED VIEW [dbo].[ABC] >>>'
END
GO  

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[ABC]
AS

    SELECT  ISNULL(Book, '') + '_' + ISNULL(OrderType,'') + '_'
            + ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), PayDate, 112), '') + '_'
            MAX(t.[InstrumentKey]) [InstrumentKey] ,
            MAX(t.[BookKey]) [BookKey] ,
            t.[OrderType],
            MAX(t.[InstrumentID]) [InstrumentID] ,
            t.PayDate ,
            FROM    dbo.Data t (NOLOCK)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ExtInstrument i ON t.InstrumentKey = i.InstrumentKey

    WHERE [STATUS] = 'LIVE'

    GROUP BY Book ,
            OrderType ,
            PayDate ,
            BackToBackBook 


GO
PRINT '<<< CREATED VIEW [dbo].[ABC] >>>'

GRANT SELECT ON dbo.ABC TO INVENTORY_READERS
GO

PRINT '<<< GRANT SELECT ON  VIEW [dbo].[ABC] TO  INVENTORY_READERS  >>>'
GO
```

Comment: So what is the problem? Do you get a error when you add your CASE? What is the error text and how did you modify the view?

Comment: Can we do it using 'UNION' by anyway???

Answer (score 1):

Trying to follow what you are asking. Is this what you mean?

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[ABC]
AS

SELECT  ISNULL(Book, '') + '_' + ISNULL(OrderType,'') + '_'
        + ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), PayDate, 112), '') + '_'
        MAX(t.[InstrumentKey]) [InstrumentKey] ,
        MAX(t.[BookKey]) [BookKey] ,
        t.[OrderType],
        MAX(t.[InstrumentID]) [InstrumentID] ,
        CASE WHEN OrderType in ('CO','IO') THEN t.ValuDate ELSE t.PayDate END AS PayDate,
        FROM    dbo.Data t (NOLOCK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ExtInstrument i ON t.InstrumentKey = i.InstrumentKey

WHERE [STATUS] = 'LIVE'

GROUP BY Book ,
        OrderType ,
        CASE WHEN OrderType in ('CO','IO') THEN t.ValuDate ELSE t.PayDate END ,
        BackToBackBook
```

EDIT: I suspect the first part needs to be

```
SELECT  ISNULL(Book, '') + '_' + ISNULL(OrderType,'') + '_'
        + ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), CASE WHEN OrderType in ('CO','IO') THEN t.ValuDate ELSE t.PayDate END, 112), '') + '_'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something which I have done. But I want to use 'UNION' & get the view modified. Can we use UNION in anyways to modify this view??

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[ABC]'))
BEGIN
    DROP VIEW [dbo].[ABC]
    PRINT '<<< DROPPED VIEW [dbo].[ABC] >>>'
END
GO  

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[ABC]
AS


SELECT  ISNULL(Book, '') + '_' + ISNULL(OrderType,'') + '_'
        + ISNULL(t.RIC, '') + '_'
        + CASE OrderType
                            WHEN OrderType = 'PNoteCorporateAction' OR 'PNoteDividendDraft' OR 'PNoteDividend' THEN ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), PayDate, 112), '') 
            ELSE ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), ValuDate, 112), '') 
          END AS PayDate + '_'  
        MAX(t.[InstrumentKey]) [InstrumentKey] ,
        MAX(t.[BookKey]) [BookKey] ,
        t.[OrderType],
        MAX(t.[InstrumentID]) [InstrumentID] ,
        t.PayDate ,
        FROM    dbo.Data t (NOLOCK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ExtInstrument i ON t.InstrumentKey = i.InstrumentKey

WHERE [STATUS] = 'LIVE'

GROUP BY Book ,
        OrderType ,
        CASE WHEN OrderType = 'PNoteCorporateAction' OR 'PNoteDividendDraft' OR 'PNoteDividend' THEN PayDate ELSE ValueDate END AS PayDate,
        BackToBackBook 


GO
PRINT '<<< CREATED VIEW [dbo].[ABC] >>>'

GRANT SELECT ON dbo.ABC TO INVENTORY_READERS
GO

PRINT '<<< GRANT SELECT ON  VIEW [dbo].[ABC] TO  INVENTORY_READERS  >>>'
GO
```

Comment: Use UNION something like:  Select  PK ....  ,  VALUEDATE *    FROM    WHERE CO/IO.......  Group By      UNION   Select  PK ....  ,  PAYDATE *    FROM   ....   WHERE Not CO/IO .......  Group By

Comment: Why do you want to use UNION? You could, yes. You seem to have the right idea with your previous comment.